# dd accordion not working. No error shown in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've set up a ddaccordion on a site but for some reason it isn't working. It stays open all the time.
I've checked that the correct library is being called and I see no errors logged in the console.

Ive set up a fiddle using the exact html, css and script as used on the site and it doesn't work in there either which rules out a conflict with other javascript or jquery.
The fiddle can be found here https://jsfiddle.net/b1ao7g05/2/

The script used is taken from a demo on the ddaccordion website and is

```
ddaccordion.init({
headerclass: "submenuheader", //Shared CSS class name of headers group
contentclass: "submenu", //Shared CSS class name of contents group
revealtype: "mouseover", //Reveal content when user clicks or onmouseover the header? Valid value: "click", "clickgo", or "mouseover"
mouseoverdelay: 200, //if revealtype="mouseover", set delay in milliseconds before header expands onMouseover
collapseprev: true, //Collapse previous content (so only one open at any time)? true/false 
defaultexpanded: [], //index of content(s) open by default [index1, index2, etc] [] denotes no content
onemustopen: false, //Specify whether at least one header should be open always (so never all headers closed)
animatedefault: false, //Should contents open by default be animated into view?
persiststate: true, //persist state of opened contents within browser session?
toggleclass: ["", ""], //Two CSS classes to be applied to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively ["class1", "class2"]
togglehtml: ["suffix", "<img src='plus.gif' class='statusicon' />", "<img src='minus.gif' class='statusicon' />"], //Additional HTML added to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively  ["position", "html1", "html2"] (see docs)
animatespeed: "fast", //speed of animation: integer in milliseconds (ie: 200), or keywords "fast", "normal", or "slow"
oninit:function(headers, expandedindices){ //custom code to run when headers have initalized
    //do nothing
},
onopenclose:function(header, index, state, isuseractivated){ //custom code to run whenever a header is opened or closed
    //do nothing
}
})
```

Any ideas what is causing the accordion to fail?

Answer (score -1):

ReferenceError: ddaccordion is not defined

1. Zencart does not support https. Even if Link is changed to https, it won't work. Reference error remains because content will not be loaded via untrustet certificates
2. The Script is using document.write (which was revealed, when I copied the ddaccordianscript into the fiddle JS-Area)
3. Ensure that the "infrastructure" of the problem works before submitting it so that users can help find the mistakes in your code, not in problems with jsfiddle.

Comment: just updated fiddle as it was looking for file over http not https
https://jsfiddle.net/b1ao7g05/3/

Comment: I don't know what you know about zen cart, but clearly not the basic fact that it does support https. It's something that is defined in the configure.php files!
With regards to the issue, I was actually referring to the fact that jsfiddle complained that the file was served over http instead of https. Try adding an http url to an outside file yourself and you will see the error message it generates.

Comment: [ ] You have checked that https://zencart.hosting/admintabs/ddaccordion.js does not generate certificate errors.